# XML Deserialization to nested array of objects. Again

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm getting some XML from a web service. I build some classes to deserialize it to. It's partially working; I get expected values for the primitive members of the `AdvMortgage` objects.

As the code is, I get a null value for the `Mortgage` field of any `AdvMortgage`. This is a similar problem to one I've posted recently, but I've really been having trouble with it. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <Product xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       ... 
      <AdvMortgage>
        <Mortage>
          <MortgageType>...</MortgageType>
          <MortgageType>...</MortgageType>
          <MortgageType>
            <apr>4.99</apr>
            <discountPts>0.00</discountPts>
            <originationFee>0.00</originationFee>
            <pgmName>7/1 Adjustable</pgmName>
            <rate>4.875</rate>
          </MortgageType>
        </Mortage>
        <mortEffectiveDate>Rates effective 12/4/2018</mortEffectiveDate>
        <mortNote>
          ARM = Adjustable Rate Mortgage
          
          ...
        </mortNote>
      </AdvMortgage>
      ...
      <effectiveDate>Rates effective from 12/01/2018 through 12/31/2018</effectiveDate>
    </Product>
```

And the classes:

```
namespace InitechServiceEntities
{
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Product
    {
        //...
        [XmlElement("AdvMortgage")]
        public AdvMortgage AdvMortgage;
        [XmlElement("effectiveDate")]
        public string effectiveDate;
    }

    [XmlType("AdvMortgage")]
    public class AdvMortgage
    {
        [XmlElement("mortEffectiveDate")]
        public string mortEffectiveDate;
        [XmlElement("mortNote")]
        public string mortNote;
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Mortgage")]
        [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(MortgageType))]
        public MortgageType[] Mortgage;
    }

    [XmlType("MortgageType")]
    public class MortgageType
    {
        [XmlElement("pgmName")]
        public string pgmName;
        [XmlElement("rate")]
        public string rate;
        [XmlElement("apr")]
        public string apr;
        [XmlElement("discountPts")]
        public string discountPts;
        [XmlElement("originationFee")]
        public string originationFee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] so we can see how you're processing the data.

Comment: `Mortgage` is not the same as `Mortage`

Comment: Try to change name of your attribute like => `[XmlArray(ElementName = "Mortage")]`

Answer (score 0):

grek40, er-shoaib, thank you. I'd been staring at that so long, and I never realized the person who wrote the service misspelled "Mortgage". I need a vacation.